# Accidentally deleted the directory using sudo rm -rf on AWS linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I accidentally deleted the project directory using sudo  rm -rf command can we have option to restore it? 
Is AWS support maintain backup of every instance.?
My running instance ec2 Linux. and deleted directory is /var/www/html/
Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: You deleted it on a instance or the AMI?

Comment: Next time, assuming "project directory" contains "source files", consider using some version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: I deleted the files form running  ec2 instance. /var/www/html directory. the command that I executed is sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/

Comment: I did not use any Git. So I there any way so that I can restore the deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not backup every ec2 instance in this way

It's easy to make your own backups with the snapshot capability but you haven't done this AWS support cannot help

(the RDS service does do some kind of automatic backups but ec2 does not)